# CSS Support- Checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have a html file, which has sections those can be expanded or collapsed. Following image has what I am trying to achieve (when collapsed, when expanded). I have also attached code (jsfiddle.net/MpPE8/).

[image: Image-1]

**Question:**
I wanted to place the checkbox (which was shown while expanded) between (+) and heading text (Heading One) when collapsed. See following image for more information. I want this to be achieved using CSS ONLY due to environment restriction.

[image: Image -2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the div as a hidden element (eq. display: none) and then show it when the block expands (eq. Display: inline)

Sorry for my late answer but I didn't had time until now. Here is what I understand you need:
jsfiddle.net/MpPE8/2/

Please apply the styling you need. I only worked on the functionality.

BR

Comment: The question was all about showing check box when collapsed. Ref see the second image. Feel free refer and update the code at jsfiddle.net/MpPE8/

Comment: I don't understand: you want the checkbox to be displayed between the sign that will expand and the heading, when the block is collapsed, and after the text when the block is expanded?

Comment: When expand ->  I wanted show like Image 1 ( Srl 2). When expand -> I wanted show like Image 2. See the check box, which is shown between (+) symbol and text.